Java Spring Get Item By User Id
I have a API in JavaSpring and i want to know how can i get All "Finances" by user id, relly got stuck on that and i want to send a body to the API that sends a UserId and get all Finance matching the user
@Entity
@Table(name = "finance")
public class Finance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String date;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer value;

My code is like this now and i have no idea what i am doing, i try to create the repository just to find out that i dont know to do that
Service:
    public ResponseEntity<Object> GetFinanceByUserId(Integer userId) {
        List<Finance> userFinances = financeRepository.findByUserId(userId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userFinances, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

Repository:
public interface FinanceRepository extends JpaRepository<Finance, Integer> {
    List<Finance> findByUserId(Integer userId);
}


It might be a little bit confusing at the beginning. But, you're problem is related to Hibernate (or any other ORM implementation you use), not Spring (Spring data). To get better help, I recommend you to improve your question providing all related code (Finance and User entities), commenting errors or "unexpected" results, etc. I hope it helps!

You can change entity like below
Entity
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long userId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private User user;

Repository
public interface FinanceRepository extends JpaRepository<Finance, Integer> {
List<Finance> findByUserId(Integer userId);
}


Adding Long userId field should be enough. Why do we need to add user field?

You should to prefer what type of relationship do you prefer: table vs entity.
If you choose table relationship your code should be like this.
Entity
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long userId;

Repository method
Set<Finance> findByUserId(Integer userId);

When you choose entity relationship, your code should be like this
Entity
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

Repository method
Set<Finance> findAllByUser(User user);

In this case you don't need to create whole user, you need do define only id field.
User user = User()
user.id = 1L

Set<Finance> finances = repository.findAllByUser(user)

You can't mixing both variants because it may produce error: "Column 'person_id' is duplicated in mapping for entity $entityName$  (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column".
Of course you can add these params insertable and updatable. But it produce new error when you tried to manage entity bidirectional way. In this case when you mixing both managing type you have to set user_id field when adding a new finance to User entity.
